# How can I get a link to Microsoft Outlook message?

Tags: macos, ms-office, automation

In prior versions of Outlook, AppleScript could be used to get a link to message/s like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
   set theSelection to (get current messages)
  ...
```

In version > 16.59, this no longer works. Is there another way to do this in new versions of Outlook?